# I got <a><the> perfect score on the exam in ring theory but not in Galois theory

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

> I got **a/the** perfect score on the exam in ring theory but not in Galois
> theory.

**Question:** Which is correct, **a** or **the**?

A perfect score is a particular number (in Japan, usually 100), so I suppose that **the** is correct; however, **a** is being used in the following sentence:

- It’s great that he got **a** perfect score on the exam. ([source](https://gogakuru.com/mypage_530295/diary/2019-09/09.html))

I am totally confused.

**[Edit]** This question is about American English. I don't know whether "perfect score" is used in other varieties of English.

Comment: The definite article is [***very*** rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+a+perfect+score%2Cachieved+the+perfect+score&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in the cited context. You nearly always *get **a** perfect score*, and offhand I can't think of even a single contrived context where ***the** perfect score* would be preferable.

Answer (score 5):

"The" is used when you refer to a single identifiable object.

In this case "100" (or whatever other top value, of course) is `a` perfect score because there are countless other "perfect scores" achieved by you or someone else in the same or other exams.
Using `the` perfect score would imply you are referring to that unique result, not to the "generic" one-hundred-value.

The fact the number is the same (100, in this case) does not imply it is unique (100 apples, 100 oranges, 100 in ring theory, 100 in Galois theory, 100 in Galois theory given to another student are all different).

Comment: Contrast "I got a perfect score on the exam" with "Even the perfect score I got on the exam wasn't enough for my parents."